# sqlite query - how do I get multiple results from a single row which is filtered by range?

Tags: sqlite, callback

I am quite new in programming and aspiring to make a game using cocos2dx and sqlite. But I came across this problem where I can't find an example on or how it can be done.

The first thing I want to do is to randomly select a row from a table which has been filtered by a range. For example there is a table with 100 rows. If I filter between the value 1 ~ 10 of Column D it resulted in 20 rows. From these 20 I want to randomly select one of them.

Secondly for that randomly selected row I want to collect 5 different value, but so far I was unable to find working example on how I can collect them.

Here is the code I try to come up with but is not working:

- Query

> ```
> int MinColumnD = 1;
> int Max ColumnD = 10;
> int Dice =  ( rand() % 19 ) + 1;
> char sql_query[100];
> sprintf(sql_query, "SELECT A, B, C, D, E FROM SQList WHERE (ColumnD BETWEEN %d AND %d) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", MinColumnD, MaxColumnD);
> std::list<INFO> details;
> sqlite3_exec(DB, sql_query, CallBack, &details, &errorMessage);
> ```

*Thanks to CL's comment I updated the above query to include order by random() Limit 1. However when I run it and get to the section I get this error on xcode:

> ```
>  Thread 1
>  0 sqlite3_exec
>  0x54cbd8: movl 60(%ebx), %eax   < Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x444e418e)
> ```

This seems to only happen when I include the 'ORDER BY RANDOM()' as part of the query

- Callback

> ```
> int CallBack( void * pOutCount, int argc, char ** argv, char **azColName ){
>
> std::list<Class::INFO> *pList = (std::list<Class::INFO >*)pOutCount;
> Class::INFO items;
> items._A = argv[0];
> items._B = atoi(argv[1]);
> items._C = atoi(argv[2]);
> items._D = atoi(argv[3]);
> items._E = atoi(argv[4]);
> pList->push_back( items );
> return 0;
>
> }
> ```

- Struct

> ```
> struct Class::INFO {
>
> std::string _A;
> int _B;
> int _C;
> int _D;
> int _E;
>
> };
> ```

*Perhaps because the sqlite query is incomplete so I don't get the result properly but I am not sure how exactly I am able to get the returned list of values from the std::list. Is it correct to think that after the query then I can just call the component inside the list to get the value like:

> ```
> std::string A = details._A;
> int B = details._B;
> int C = details._C;
> int D = details._D;
> int E = details._E;
> ```

Please help!

Comment: What is your problem with the callback?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. Could you show a minimal but complete program that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not know which `rowid`s end up in the filtered result, so you cannot use them.

To get some random records from the filtered result, first order it [randomly](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#random), then [take the first record](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) of that:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E
FROM SQList
WHERE ColumnD BETWEEN ? AND ?
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you! what would also be the best way to collect the info of A, B, C, D, E and place it into individual int or char?

Comment: Your callback looks OK at first glance. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: Currently when I use ORDER BY RANDOM() I get a exc bad access in xcode.

Then I am trying to extract the data from std::list<INFO> details but... just doing int B = details._B doesn't seem to do it. Not too sure how I am suppose to do.

Comment: Put those details into the question. And you should tell where exactly you get the exception.

Comment: Hi CL, I've updated the question with the problem. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: I think the 1st part is solved, but still having great difficulties on the 2nd part. I will create a new question for this.